# internet restore without firmware support

Tags: macbook-pro, recovery

my Mac is not supported for Internet recovery, is there any other way/option to do Internet Recovery (boot-able tool to launch Internet Recovery )?

edit: Macbookpro2,2 with blank hard-disk

Comment: please add the Mac Identifier (e.g. MacBookPro4,1) and specify your problems (no dvd-device, no system dvd etc.) and your network environment. Maybe we find workarounds...

Comment: If you have a working Mac (or access to anyone else's working Mac), you can create a bootable OS X installer on a flash drive. That's what I do, since I can't do internet recovery either. Search "createinstallmedia" and you should find good instructions. (As far as I know, you won't get internet recovery unless Apple supports your Mac already.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way, the firmware required to do that is signed by Apple. There is no custom firmware for OS X devices.

Comment: is there any tool from apple? for this task

Comment: No there is no way to flash custom firmware period.